# Sencha keyed many to one relation, with complex (namespace) name

Tags: extjs, many-to-one, auto-generate, extjs6-modern

The [official documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.data.schema.ManyToOne.html) on sencha has a simple example of a many-to-one relationship. It uses "reference" field to identify the relationship.

A slightly modified example is below, this works:

```
Ext.define('Customer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name']
});

Ext.define('Ticket', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'title', {
        name: 'customerId',
        reference: 'Customer'
    }]
});
const customer = new Customer({id: '1', name: 'paul'});
const ticket = new Ticket({id: '1000', title: 'blah', customerId: '1'});
const t = customer.tickets();
const c = ticket.getCustomer();
console.dir(t);
console.dir(c);
```

Now I tried to modify this further, by renaming the "`Customer`" class to use a namespace (as per conventionion in sencha):

```
Ext.define('Long.Name.Customer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name']
});

Ext.define('Ticket', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'title', {
        name: 'customerId',
        reference: 'Long.Name.Customer'
    }]
});
const customer = new Long.Name.Customer({id: '1', name: 'paul'});
const ticket = new Ticket({id: '1000', title: 'blah', customerId: '1'});
const t = customer.tickets();
const c = ticket.getCustomer();
```

However now suddenly the classes aren't generated anymore and there is an array that `customers.tickets` isn't defined (and `ticket.getCustomer` is also not defined).

How do I use namespaces with many-to-one relations?

And furthermore: what are the rules for the generated method? -- I notice 
`Customer.tickets()` uses plural (adds `-s` to the function name): what would happen on a word that ends on 's'? Are there "rules" for these generated methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the use of namespace I found a solution, [the getterName](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.data.schema.Reference.html#cfg-getterName) property of the reference field helps. Together with the complementory [inverse](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.data.schema.Reference.html#cfg-inverse). The definition for the `Ticket` class would then become:

```
Ext.define('Ticket', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'title', {
        name: 'customerId',
        reference: {
            type: 'Look.Out.Customer',
            inverse: 'tickets',
            getterName: 'getCustomer',
            setterName: 'setCustomer',
        }
    }]
});
```

While I was unable to find information regarding the automated naming (other than "it's based on the role and mostly add -s"), being able to manually name the generated methods sidesteps the issue.